# Delphi - Multithreading: Why I can't start thread again after thread.terminate()?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe3

I've coding a `multithread` application that send and receive TCP packages. I'm with the problem that when I call twice event `confirmBoxRecognized(peerIP: string)` of the code bellow. I'm getting the following exception:

> Cannot call Start on a running or suspended thread

If I check in the thread object I've that `terminated == true` and `suspended == false`. Why am I coding wrong?

Following the code:

```
TThreadReadTCP = class(TThread)

  private

    context: TfrmBoxTest;
    looping: Boolean;

    procedure readTCP;
  protected
    procedure DoTerminate; override;
    procedure Execute; override;

  public
    peerIP: String;
    responseObject: TProtocolObject;

    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; ctx: TFrmBoxTest); overload;


  end;


{ TThreadReadTCP }

constructor TThreadReadTCP.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; ctx: TFrmBoxTest);
begin
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
  Self.context := ctx;
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;


procedure TThreadReadTCP.DoTerminate;
begin

  looping := false;
  inherited DoTerminate();

end;

procedure TThreadReadTCP.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  looping := true;
  readTCP;
end;

procedure TThreadReadTCP.readTCP;
var
  buffer: TBytes;
begin

  while looping do
  begin

    if context.tcpClientBox.Connected then
    begin

      try

        buffer := TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(context.tcpClientBox.Socket.ReadLn());

        //do something else

      except on E:Exception  do
        ShowMessage('Error receiving TCP buffer with message: ' + e.Message);
      end;

    end;

  end;

end;



procedure TfrmBoxTest.confirmBoxRecognized(peerIP: string);
begin
  if (connectBoxTCP(peerIP)) then
  begin
    if Assigned(threadReadTCP) then
    begin
      threadReadTCP.Terminate();
      threadReadTCP.Start(); // I get the exception here when I run this code twice...
    end;
    showBoxRecognized();
  end;
  sendBoxRecognized();
end;
```

Are there running thread status can I get? Or anyone can explain how can I improve this code to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So the thread is `terminated=true` but it's not finished?

Comment: Just like that.

Comment: `terminated` is just a boolean you can set if you want your thread to terminate. Instead of checking for `looping`, you can can check for `terminated` in your while loop to end it.

Comment: does the TCP connection inside this thread prevent it from being terminated? I tried using `WaitFor`, but the app freezes

Comment: AFAIK, I don't recall it ever being possible to restart a terminated thread. Never even tried it. Terminated means terminated. If you want to re-start it, then don't terminate it. Keep it in a loop which checks some flag for whether or not it should proceed. If not, then just keep looping and checking. Either that, or just start a fresh copy of the thread. And indeed, if you use `FreeOnTerminate`, then from the exact moment you call `Start`, you do *NOT* want to even so much as keep a reference to this thread. It must be ignored from that moment. Declare a local variable, not in the form.

Comment: Also, good thread design would be to isolate it from any and all UI controls. This is best accomplished by writing the thread in its own unit, which doesn't even use any VCL units. It should be self-contained, and unaware of how it's being used. UI updates should be synchronized in some way. I personally prefer triggering synchronized events. In any case, *a thread cannot directly access any UI controls in the main UI thread*, as they are not thread safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the exception because you can only call `Start()` on a `TThread` object one time.  Once the thread has been started, you cannot restart it.  Once it has been signaled to terminate, all you can do is wait for it to finish terminating, and then destroy the object.

If you want another thread to start running, you have to create a new `TThread` object, eg:

```
type
  TThreadReadTCP = class(TThread)
  private
    context: TfrmBoxTest;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure TerminatedSet; override;
  public
    peerIP: String;
    responseObject: TProtocolObject;
    constructor Create(ctx: TFrmBoxTest); reintroduce;
  end;

constructor TThreadReadTCP.Create(ctx: TFrmBoxTest);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  Self.context := ctx;

  // NEVER use FreeOnTerminate=True with a thread object that you keep a reference to!
  // FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

procedure TThreadReadTCP.Execute;
var
  buffer: TBytes;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    try
      buffer := TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(context.tcpClientBox.Socket.ReadLn());
      // do something else
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        // do something
        raise;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TThreadReadTCP.TerminatedSet;
begin
  try
    context.tcpClientBox.Disconnect(False);
  except
  end;
end;

...

procedure TfrmBoxTest.confirmBoxRecognized(peerIP: string);
begin
  if Assigned(threadReadTCP) then
  begin
    threadReadTCP.Terminate();
    threadReadTCP.WaitFor();
    FreeAndNil(threadReadTCP);
  end;
  if connectBoxTCP(peerIP) then
  begin
    threadReadTCP := TThreadReadTCP.Create(Self);
    showBoxRecognized();
  end;
  sendBoxRecognized();
end;
```

Comment: Thanks @Remy Labeau for the amazing answer! I've a last question. After call `TerminatedSet` `Execute` raise an exception saying: "Not connected". Is it the normal behavior?

Comment: @pedro.olimpio yes, because `Terminate()` calls `TerminatedSet()` to disconnect the socket while `Execute()` is running. It is the only way to unblock `ReadLn()` unless you use a read timeout when calling `ReadLn()`